# Parameters.xml in scwdp. What and how?

Tags: deployment, setup, settings

I was looking into Sitecore set-up on Azure.
I downloaded the scwdp packages from the Sitecore portal.
Inside the scwdp packages, there is a file with the name `parameters.xml`.

I am not being able to:

1. what is the use of the file
2. how to use the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parameters.xml` file is used by Sitecore installation of the scwdp packages in Azure.

You generally don't need to touch or edit this file in the package.

There will be .json files like `azuredeploy.json`, `parameters.json` where you'll specify the necessary settings and configurations like `Azure instance names, sql server database prefixes`, etc and the installation takes care of passing this information to the parameters.xml file inside the scwdp package accordingly.

Comment: Please help me at what stage and how it is used. I have got into an existing project and we have this file. We are not able to figure out how it is being used.

Comment: This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ff398068(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN contains details the web deploy packages and how parameters are passed at runtime through parameters.xml. Hope this helps!